# htaccess Rewrite rule to accept Hindi characters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a link like this
[www.example.com/profile.php?name=sagar123](http://www.example.com/profile.php?name=sagar123)

I used this rule:

`RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]`

and now I can chang my URL to like this:

[www.example.com/profile/sagar123](http://www.example.com/profile/sagar123)

everything is fine but, now I want to use Hindi language characters also like this

[www.example.com/profile.php?name=सागर](http://www.example.com/profile.php?name=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B0) (It's working fine)

[www.example.com/profile/सागर](http://www.example.com/profile/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B0) (It is not working and showing Server error)

Please help me to write a rule or regex to accept all ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) and also Hindi Character.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: @sagar, Did the below answer helped you in any way? If yes, would you accept the answer ? THanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hindi chars falls  between `\u0900-\u097F` range. So you can use this inside character class.

To answer your question, most regexes(`PCRE`) do not support `\u` notation and support format of `\x{900}`

```
([\x{900}-\x{97F}a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
```

In python `\u` is supported, so :

```
([\u0900-\u097Fa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
```

see [this](https://regex101.com/r/zCG6RZ/1) for regex matching demonstrating both English and Hindi chars getting matched.

Also, see [this](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F) for reading literal hindi char mapped to their hex values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `(.*)` regex class to match any type of character.

Also, you don't need the `+` operator at the end in your capturing `(` and `)` parens, as you're using `^` to indicate the beginning of the URL line, and `$` to indicate its end, so a `+` greedy operator doesn't get you anything extra.

It should look like...

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

If you need further info, I recommend taking a look at [**Apache.org: Apache mod_rewrite Introduction**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html).  They cover most of the characters I've discussed in this post up to this point: `.`, `(`, `)`, `+`, etc..